# Trying to learn tensorflow.js but need a simpler example like brain.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js, brain.js

The examples for brain.js allowed me to understand the software really well - and various aspects of machine learning.

It's hard to replicate the same kind of code now that I'm trying to learn tensorflow.js.

For example, what is the TensorFlow equivalent to the following brain code?

```
var net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

net.train([{input: { r: 0.03, g: 0.7, b: 0.5 }, output: { black: 1 }},
       {input: { r: 0.16, g: 0.09, b: 0.2 }, output: { white: 1 }},
       {input: { r: 0.5, g: 0.5, b: 1.0 }, output: { white: 1 }}]);

var output = net.run({ r: 1, g: 0.4, b: 0 });  // { white: 0.99, black: 0.002 }
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I felt that was a good question. If I said something wrong or came off offensive, my sincere apologies. I don't know what I did to get the downvote - please do tell me. If I don't know, I can't correct myself for the future.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be a kind of simplified version of your provided example:

```js
const net = tf.sequential();
net.add(tf.layers.dense({
  units: 2,
  inputShape: [3],
  activation: 'sigmoid'
}));
net.compile({
  loss: 'meanSquaredError',
  optimizer: 'sgd'
});

const xs = tf.tensor2d([
  [0.03, 0.7, 0.5],
  [0.16, 0.09, 0.2],
  [0.5, 0.5, 1.0]
]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([
  [1, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [0, 1]
]);

net.fit(xs, ys).then(() => {
  const xPredict = tf.tensor2d([
    [1.0, 0.4, 0.0]
  ]);

  const prediction = net.predict(xPredict);
  prediction.print();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.6">
</script>
```

But as you can see, you have to be much more specific about what the neural network actually does. I just used on of the basic options you can use. And as you can see the network performs very poorly because of this, but I hope you get an idea of how this works. so let me try to explain what this snippet does:

`const` is generally used for `tf.tensor`s because they live on the GPU so they can't be changed anyway.

[`tf.sequential()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#sequential) creates an empty feed forward network. (If you don't know what that is try learning about neural nets first without there implementation)

[`tf.layers.dense()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#layers.dense) creates a fully connected layer.

`units:2` defines the output shape of the layer. In this case a  vector with two values.

`inputShape: [3]` can be ignored on any non-first layer, because it can be inferred by the previous one and defines the shape of the input tensors

`activation: 'sigmoid'` is the activation function that is applied to the return value of the layer and is highly dependend on the problem you want to solve.

[`.compile()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#tf.Model.compile) compiles the network with the given option and is also very customizable

`xs` and `ys` are the training data sets. Note: they have one additional dimension to represent more than one x-y-pair, so they can be passed to training function in batches.

[`.fit()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#tf.Sequential.fit) is the training method and trains the internal weights of the network. Note: this is an asynchronous function, so you have to wait until it'S finished until you can use the model.

`xPredict` is the test data, also one dimension higher than the return shape of the network.

[`.predict()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#tf.Sequential.predict) predicts the output of the network based on the given input.

[`.print()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/#tf.Tensor.print) outputs the tensor in the console. (If it's too big, it gets cropped)

I highly encourage you to learn more about neural nets first, before you try to implement them (by copying), because they can get really complicated and confusing. Then you can read the documantation to see what's possible.

Comment: Thank you sir! You made my day. I shall study this and read up much more on neural nets. Thanks for taking the time to explain each aspect of the code as well.